# Having problems with printing out a double

Tags: java

So I have this line of code

```
output.println("Nimi: %s | Keskmine hinne %f | Aine: %s", i.askName(), i.askMedian(), i.askSubject());
```

So the the first and last one are strings but the middle one is a double. Now to print a double I know that you have to use %f right? But for some reason Eclipse is giving me this error:

```
The method println(String) in the type PrintWriter is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, double, String)
```

What is the problem here?  Why is the error even showing like I am trying to use 4 variables here when I am only using 3?

Comment: You're looking for `printf`, not `println`.

Comment: No *I am printing this into a file and it all happens in a for loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use printf() not println(). println() does not allow text formatting.

Answer (score 4):

Use `String.format`

```
output.println(String.format("Nimi: %s | Keskmine hinne %f | Aine: %s", i.askName(), i.askMedian(), i.askSubject()));
```